# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: java, mysql, spring, recv

all.
I have encounter the problem for some days, this is the detail stack information:

```
org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 18,940 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 18,918 milliseconds ago.
### The error may involve com.tuan800.searchtask.model.dao.mybatis.RelationDao.updateSuggest-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 18,940 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 18,918 milliseconds ago.
; SQL []; Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 18,940 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 18,918 milliseconds ago.; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 18,940 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 18,918 milliseconds ago.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:71)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:346)
    at $Proxy10.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.update(SqlSessionTemplate.java:245)
    at com.tuan800.searchtask.model.dao.mybatis.impl.RelationDaoImpl.updateSuggest(RelationDaoImpl.java:24)
    at com.tuan800.searchtask.service.impl.RelationServiceImpl.modifyRelationCount(RelationServiceImpl.java:64)
    at com.tuan800.searchtask.RelationIndexTask.main(RelationIndexTask.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 18,940 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 18,918 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1118)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2941)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3489)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1364)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.execute(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:989)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor163.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:45)
    at $Proxy20.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:22)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:51)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:29)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:88)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor165.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:338)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2499)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2952)
    ... 32 more
```

I want update a record in mysql by mybatis and spring,and I update it one by one,below is mybatis config:

      update suggestions set count = #{count},version=#{version},freq=#{freq} where id = #{id}

And the service code:

```
for(RelationBvo relation : list){

       Long totalCount = solrDealService.queryResult(relation.getWord(),null,null,0);

       relation.setCount(totalCount.intValue());

       if(relation.getFreq() == 0){
            relation.setFreq(1);
       }

       ***relationDao.updateSuggest(relation);//update record***

       executedCount++;

       logger.info("Program have executed "+executedCount+" records.");
}
```

can anyone help me?thanks very much.

Comment: Looks like the MySQL server stopped responding.  Does it always happen at the same place?  What do the MySQL server logs say? Any error messages there?

Comment: Jim Garrison,I have fixed it by add useCompression=true when connection is established.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mySQL connections are timing out before your connection pool recognizes them. There are multiple ways to fix this:

1. Increase the timeout value in mysql config file (my.ini)
2. Reduce the idle time in your connection pool, so that it will discard the connection before mysql will close it
3. Add a validate connection query in your pool config so that the pool tests each connection before it gives it to you, but this can slow down the system terribly.