# Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ibatis

Getting below exception on my prod server, but it resolves automatically after few hours. What could be the reason for this issue

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was234747 milliseconds ago.The last packet sent successfully to the server was 234747 milliseconds ago, which  is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

We have set autoReconnect=true already,  From Forums I found that we need enable idle connections test. Please advise

Will it be any unclosed connections in the application causes this exception?

we use Ibatis and below is the Ibatisconfig file

```
<transactionManager type="JDBC" commitRequired="true">
    <dataSource type="SIMPLE">
        <property name="JDBC.Driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL"
            value="<URL>?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="JDBC.Username" value="<username>" />
        <property name="JDBC.Password" value="<password>" />
        <property name="JDBC.DefaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
        <property name="Pool.TimeToWait" value="100" />
        <property name="Pool.PingQuery" value="select 1" />
        <property name="Pool.PingEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="Pool.PingConnectionsOlderThan" value="300000" />
        <property name="Pool.PingConnectionsNotUsedFor" value="300000" />
    </dataSource>
</transactionManager>
```

Comment: Have you checked your SQL server logs? Possibly relevant SO threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511855/reproduce-com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-with-a-setup-o and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527459/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my project I faced the same issue. We use mysql, and if the connection is idle for 8 hours then db goes unavailable. The solution we used was using C3P0 connection pool. Check about this in here.
http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/

Comment: do they have an option for Ibatis, I heard its for Hibernate

Comment: We've never used Ibatis before. After reading your comment I googled about it and I found one article. Hope this'll help you.http://www.opendebug.com/article/447235